# How to send push notifications using UDID in PHP

Tags: php, push-notification, udid

I have a requirement where i need to send push notification using UDID instead of Device token, I have a working code which can send push notification using device token but i have to be able to send it using UDID as well

```
    <?php
    $deviceToken = $_POST['devicetoken'];
    $passphrase = '***********************';
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'dist.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

    $body['aps'] = array(
      'alert' => $message,
      'sound' => 'default',
      'date' => date('U')
      );

    $payload = json_encode($body);

    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;


    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
    echo $message ;
    if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . $result;

    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, Apple has started rejecting application which uses UDID for Push notifications. I recommend reviewing Apple terms before implementing push notification with UDID.

Comment: Yes but I want to send push notifications to the devices that installed the app before the UDID was deprecated by apple

Comment: check out this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061384/apple-push-notification-with-device-token-and-udid there is reference provided to implement push notifications with UDID